# the item that repeated a specified number of times in spark (scala)

Tags: list, scala, apache-spark

I want to know the items that repeated a specified number of times in Spark (Scala).

With an `RDD` like this:

`rdd = [text1,text2,text3,text4,text2,text4,text1,text1]`

if the **time = 2** the output should be **[text2,text4]**.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have an `RDD` that has been created like this:

```scala
val df: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  "text1", "text2", "text3", "text1", "text2", "text4"
))
```

You can use `countByValue` followed by a `filter` and `keys`, where 2 is your `time` value:

```scala
df.countByValue().filter(tuple => tuple._2 == 2).keys
```

If we do a `println`, we ge the following output:

```
[text1, text2]
```

Hope this is what you want, good luck!